# Flutter push notification open url instead App Android

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am facing an issue with handling notifications in my Android app. Currently, when a user taps on a notification, it opens the app. However, I want to implement a functionality where tapping on the notification opens a specific URL instead.

Here's a bit more context:

Notifications are being sent from Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM).
Each notification contains a URL that I want to open when the user taps on it.
I have looked into the documentation and some tutorials, but I couldn't find a clear solution for this particular scenario. I'm wondering if there's a specific way to intercept the notification tap event and redirect it to open a URL instead of launching the app.

Any guidance, code examples, or suggestions on how to achieve this would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!